# neuralnet package and dependent variable with text category

Tags: r, neural-network

I use neuralnet package and as example i took classical dataset of iris(Fisher).
So i have 4 independent vars (SEPALLEN,SEPALWID,PETALLEN,PETALWID)it's numeric. And dependent var is IRISTYPE with three text category(SETOSA,VIRGINIC  VERSICOL)
my syntax

```
nn=neuralnet(IRISTYPE~SEPALLEN+SEPALWID+PETALLEN+PETALWID,
             data=infert,hidden=2,err.fct="ce",linear.output = FALSE )
```

and i have error

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'IRISTYPE' not found
```

I understand that problem only in that my dependent var is  text. 
How to do, that R could work with text dependent var. Is it required any transformation? or maybe  i need another syntax to work with it.

Comment: You need `IRISTYPE` column to exist in `infert` data.

Comment: As Pascal notes, there is no `IRISTYPE` in `infert`.  Furthermore, those are not the variable names in the `iris` dataset.  Please do look at the actual example in the `neuralnet` package.  If the variables are not in the dataset, you cannot reasonably expect the function to work.

Comment: o i'm sorry, i gave other syntax. that my syntax
d=read.csv("C:/1/ir.csv",sep=";")
nn=neuralnet(IRISTYPE~SEPALLEN+SEPALWID+PETALLEN+PETALWID,
             data=d,hidden=2,err.fct="ce",linear.output = FALSE )


Error in neurons[[i]] %*% weights[[i]] : 
  requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments
i;m sorry that i wrong asked. I so tired. but now we see that error, how do text in numeric?